# Is it possible to pivot header as column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'd like to know if it's possible to get to the second table given the first one with pandas. How should I do it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you want to use the `melt` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['Year1','Year2'], var_name='Year', value_name='Date')
```

`df` is Your dataframe.

Comment: It worked for me! 

pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['Year1','Year2'],
        var_name='Year', value_name='Date')